# How can I find out the language from a character?

Tags: windows, delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

Given a Unicode character, we want to find out what languages include this character, and more importantly, understand whether or not each language is `Left-To-Right`.
For example, the character `A` might be both `English` and `Spanish` which are both LTR languages.

I want this for my own text editor.
Can anyone help me in finding an API function or something that solves my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that there's an API for this in Windows. I think the way you do this is to perform your own lookup of the Unicode Character Database: http://www.unicode.org/ucd/  or find a library that does so. I suspect that ICU will do so.

Comment: What about ⌬, ∬, ✄, and ↸?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand They are BIDI neutral. It's all in the UCD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode-wise, LTR/RTL is a property of characters, not of the languages that use that character. This matters because embedded English in an Arabic text should be displayed left-to-right, even if for simplicity the document as a whole may be marked as Arabic. If you're using [JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library), these properties can be obtained using the [`UnicodeIsLeftToRight`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:UnicodeIsLeftToRight) and [`UnicodeIsRightToLeft`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:UnicodeIsRightToLeft) functions. Note that characters may be neither left-to-right nor right-to-left, and also note that JCL uses a private copy of the Unicode character list that may be a subtly different version from what any specific version of Windows uses.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question in the title, you would need to carry out an extensive study of the use of characters in the languages of the world. There are a few thousands of languages, though many of them have no regular writing system; on the other hand, some languages have several writing systems. Different variants of a language may have different repertoires of characters.

So it would be a major effort, though *some* data has been compiled e.g. in the [CLDR](http://clrd.unicode.org) repertoire – but the concept “characters used in a language” is far from clear. (Are the characters æ, è, and ö used in English? They sure appear in some forms of written English.)

So it would be unrealistic to expect to find a library routine for such purposes.

Apparently your real need was for deciding whether a character is a left-to-right character or a right-to-left character. But for completeness, I have provided an answer to what you actually asked and that might be relevant in some other contexts.